# Accidentally changed PATH variable and I cant change it back, or use vim etc..help

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc, paths

I know there are many questions like this, but I unfortunately dont know enough about Ubuntu to be able to apply it to my situation. I have all my stuff saved for work on a remote machine, that i access via ssh. I was trying to change something with a conda environment i have there, and changed something in the .bashrc file, and now I cant use vim, or ls - no text editor or command seems to work.

`echo $PATH`
returns:
`/home/percyrou/bin:/home/percyrou/bin:/home/user/bin:~/ghf_env/bin/`

as far as i remember from the .bashrc file before i accidentally changed it, the PATH was just something like : `/home/user/bin:`

I think all these extra parts got added because i tried to change it with :

`echo 'export PATH="/home/percyrou/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc` (or just with user instead of percyrou, because i wasnt sure which it was), and it seems to add it to the PATH rather than replace it. I did already run `source ~/.bashrc`

i also tried to use `scp` to download the .bashrc file to my local machin and edit there, but that also returns `bash: scp: command not found`, i guess because `scp` is also contained in my .bashrc file.

Please help! I have no idea how to proceed from here to access my path variable again. :(

Comment: When your PATH is broken, use full path to executable like `/usr/bin/scp` instead of `scp`.

Comment: You could add /usr/bin to PATH so "scp", "ls", etc can be found.  export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH.

Comment: Your vim is there: `/usr/bin/vim`

Answer (score 5):

You are still able to use `scp` and other commands, only you need to type the absolute path like `/usr/bin/scp` instead of just `scp` (or similarly `/usr/bin/ls` instead of `ls` etc.) because the shell cannot find these commands on your `$PATH`.

Try `/usr/bin/cat .bashrc` to display the contents of your `.bashrc` file or `/usr/bin/vim .bashrc` to edit it. If you can't make the file work properly by editing it, there is a default `.bashrc` file (that is copied to each user's home directory when creating account) under `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. Use the following command to copy it over your current `.bashrc` file:

```
/usr/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc .bashrc
```

Comment: Okay this is great thank you !Its still not working yet, but at least with ```/usr/bin/vim``` i can at least open it, thanks already so good to know!

Comment: Okay I copied over the default, and it still doesnt work. But since my question was mostly about how to access my stuff again, your answer was a success! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Did you log in again to a new session after copying the default? It's strange that the default file doesn't work... What is your `$PATH` after logging in to a new session with default `.bashrc` file?

Answer (score 0):

Reset your path to a minimum usable version

```sh
PATH=$(getconf PATH)
```

Then fix your .bashrc